# Formatting an document input field that shows automatically dots and hyphens but not allowing them when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm currently working in user creation login page for an e-commerce and I need to achieve something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JJBeZG-oyzrh8vCDRMjfv03oGDjrWwZw/view?usp=sharing (The video has to be seen on fullscreen, otherwise it'll be too small to detail anything)

Thing is I should not allow any special characters when the form is submitted and I think I already solved that:

```
$('#login_form #document').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
  let count = this.selectionStart,
      regex = /[^a-z0-9]/gi,
      value = $(this).val();
      console.log(value)
  if(regex.test(value)) {
    $(this).val(value.replace(regex, ''));
    count--;
  }

  this.setSelectionRange(count, count);
});
```

But I can't really think in a way to show the dots and hyphens and not allowing them on submit.

Also, any recommendation to improve the code will be well receive. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the formatting from your front-end, do some reverse reformatting in backend instead, example you input `10,000.00` then you submit it using backend PHP just replace "," str_replace(',', '', '10,000.00') then you will get **10000.00** then use `$new_number = (float)10000.00`

```
$input_number = '10,000.00';
$input_number_no_comma =  str_replace(',', '', $input_number);
$input_number_new = (float)$input_number_no_comma;

echo $input_number_new ;
```